# Apache camel multicast (ftps & file) producing empty file

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I have created a camel (2.20.1) route using groovy DSL. I need to use multicast for 2 endpoints viz. ftps and file. If the order of routes is ftps and file then file is property written on ftp server but on file system empty file is written (with size 0 bytes). If i reverse the order i.e. file and then ftps then file is written on file system properly and empty file is written on ftp server.
It is working fine on Apache Mina FTP server, but with client ftp server it is working as mentioned above.

I have tried both multicast options:

```
.to("ftps:....").to("file:...")
```

as well as

```
.to("ftps:...").to("file:..."))
```

Also tried `parallelProcessing()`, but still the same result.

```
camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
 def void configure() {
  from("file:///home/xyz/?fileName=file.txt&charset=utf-8&noop=true")
   .multicast()
   .to("ftps://localhost:21/files?username=anonymous&password=anonymous&binary=true&fileName=file.txt&passiveMode=true&fileExist=Fail")
   .to("file://${directory}?fileName=\${file:name}-\${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}")
 }
})
```

I am expecting that multicast should write the same content to both endpoints without data loss.

Answer (score 0):

See [Why is my message empty?](http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html). File consumer returns `InputStream`, which is consumed by first endpoint and thus is empty for the second endpoint. You need to enable [Stream Caching](https://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html), or convert body to some reusable object (e.g. `String`) before multicasting.

**Enable stream caching:**

```
from("file:///home/xyz/?fileName=file.txt&charset=utf-8&noop=true")
    .streamCaching()
    .multicast()
    ...
```

**Convert body:**

```
from("file:///home/xyz/?fileName=file.txt&charset=utf-8&noop=true")
    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
    .multicast()
    ...
```